# Wordpress Custom Query - Comparing Dates and Making Events List

Tags: wordpress, lifelines

this is a WordPress (lifeline theme ) I want to show upcoming event ... &
past event separately ...
Help me to write Custom Query

Comment: that things you can do it from theme settings ,so first check over there

Comment: https://lrsj.risingstarconsultancy.com/event-list-with-l-s/   this is a event page

Comment: https://snag.gy/dgo2yK.jpg...    i can provide code ..